# Mpandroid range background

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello i am using this solution [MpAndroidChart set background between limit lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406003/mpandroidchart-set-background-between-limit-lines) but graph lines are hiding behind the background color see the below image.

enter image description here

[image]

Give me any solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show me your code then I will help u out of this

Comment: Hi this is my code

Comment: float rangeLow = 66f;
        float rangeHigh = 120f;

        YAxis fillAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();

        float increment = (rangeHigh - rangeLow) / 20;
        float metricLine = rangeLow;

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            LimitLine llRange = new LimitLine(metricLine, "");
            llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#f2befb"));
            llRange.setLineWidth(100f);
            fillAxis.addLimitLine(llRange);
            metricLine = metricLine + increment;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
 llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#f2befb"));
```

Use this:

```
 llRange.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#80f2befb"));
```

I added 80 in start of your color which makes it 50% transparent. For transperancy you can add number before your color hex code as follows:

```
0% = #00
10% = #16
20% = #32
30% = #48
40% = #64
50% = #80
60% = #96
70% = #112
80% = #128
90% = #144
```

Comment: It will work try this buddy and let me know also please dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Buddy Mark my post as answer then :)

Comment: I am not sure about that but you can adjust transparency to achieve this as it feels like its above shaded area :)

Answer (score 1):

```
YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.