# MPAndroidChart: setting last line as transparent hides other lines

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a LineChart with several datasets that the user can show/hide. The algorithm to show/hide each dataset is something like this:

```
LineDataSet set = chart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(item.getIndex());
int color = item.isEnabled() ? Color.TRANSPARENT : item.getColor();
set.setColor(color);
set.setCircleColorHole(color);
set.setCircleColor(color);
set.setDrawValues(!item.isEnabled());
chart.invalidate();
```

It works perfect for the n-1 first datasets, but when applied to the last dataset the lines of the other datasets disappear too (circles and text values remain, but the lines joining each circle are transparent). The weird thing is that if i change TRANSPARENT for any other color (Ex: RED) it works as expected.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Check this, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268519/how-to-change-dot-colors-if-value-is-higher-than-constant-in-mpandroidchart/37389595#37389595

Comment: Hi @Dhruv, my problem is not with setting entrie's color, but setting the last  datasets line color as transparent "override" the others datasets line color too.

Answer (score 2):

The solution i found was to use

```
Color.<Chart background color>
```

instead of Color.Transparent