# MPAndroidChart I want to change dot color if the value over the constant

Tags: mpandroidchart

I want to make a linechart that

for many values, if there are values that over constant,

its dot color changed to another color

[How to change dot colors if value is higher than constant in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268519/how-to-change-dot-colors-if-value-is-higher-than-constant-in-mpandroidchart)

I read this and try to follow this, but it changed bar not dots

what can i do?

here's my code

private void setData(int count, int range)

```
   ArrayList<Integer> color = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
    float val = (float) (Math.random()*range);
    if (val > 50){

        //color.add(Color.RED);
        //color.add(ColorTemplate.rgb("ff0000"));
        yVals1.add(new Entry(i, val));
    } else {


        //color.add(Color.BLACK);
       // color.add(ColorTemplate.rgb("000000"));
        yVals1.add(new Entry(i, val));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace following line:

```
color.add(Color.RED);
```

with:

```
color.add(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_defined_color_in_colors_xml));
```

then after your code you need to add following line:

```
dataSet.setCircleColors(color);
```